# Remove na row index from PySpark DataFrame

Tags: pyspark

[image: DataFrame and Code]

I am not able to remove the first row.

Comment: do you have an issue with spark dataframe or pandas dataframe.?

Comment: This is spark dataframe.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna, u could use how=any, and subset all your columns, except vendor id as it has \r in it.

Comment: Right,
I also got an alternate solution to get rid of the complete row, `ddf = ddf.where(ddf['VendorId']!='\r')`

Comment: Yes you are right, But I don't know a way to copy data frame while conserving its structure.

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi
 `ddf = ddf.where(ddf['VendorId']!='\r')` is this an effective approach?

Comment: @palash it is effective if you know for sure the only row you are trying to get rid off has '\r' as vendor id. A generic solution would use dropna with how=all and subset=all columns except vendorid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your solution with where clause, you could use these too. Yours would only filter out vendorID with \r, these will filter out all rows with have all nones in all other columns, irrespective of what you have as VendorID

Filter:

```
df.filter((' or '.join([''+x+' is not null' for x in df.columns if x !='VendorID'])))
```

Dropna:

```
df.dropna(how='all', subset=[x for x in df.columns if x!='VendorID'])
```